# Yii: $_SESSION undefined, but Yii::app()->session works

Tags: php, session, yii, comet

I have enabled session within my application like this (in `config.php`, `components` section):

```
'session' => array(
    'class' => 'system.web.CDbHttpSession',
    'connectionID' => 'db',
    'timeout' => 86400,
    'sessionName' => 'SOMEABSTRACT_PHPSESSID',
),
```

In `UserIdentity` I try to do this:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $model->id;
```

Which means that I will set that new session after I log in my user. But when I try to access the `$_SESSION['userid']` or just `$_SESSION` — for reading — I get this exception:

```
Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

This is the way I'm trying to access this session array:

```
echo '<pre>';
die(var_dump($_SESSION, $_SESSION['userid']));
```

I don't have any clues about this, so my two simple questions for this issue are:

1. Why is this happening only when Yii's sessions are enabled and `autoStart => true`?
2. How to fix this?

PS I need this for CometChat integration with Yii framework.

Comment: in config, is session autostart is true or not..?

Comment: Yes. When I put `session_start()`, but I don't get the `$_SESSION['userid']` at all. But if I set `session_start()` when I try to set the session, I get this exception: `A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`

Comment: @NaincyGupta - By default, it's `true`.

Comment: facing same issue. tell me if you find solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can have `@session_start();`. This will suppress the warnings if it session already starts and also set the variable like this `Yii::app()->session['userid'] = $model->id;` and retrieve the same with `Yii::app()->session['userid']` wherever it is required.
Also you can set the logged in user like this after session start

```
 $this->_id=$model->id;
 $this->setState('title', $model->username);
 $this->setState('role', $model->role);
```

Above are the default variables in yii for logged in users. To create new user entry in session you can have this `Yii::app()->session['variablename']`

Comment: I have to access a Session Variable outside of my Yii project scope. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, in your **UserIdentity.php** -

```
//After successfully authentication, create session

    Yii::app()->session;
    Yii::app()->session['userid'] = $user->id;


//Now you can get anywhere like this - 

   echo Yii::app()->session['userid'];
```

Comment: I have to access a Session Variable outside of my Yii project scope. This won't work.

Comment: @Karadža session variable working inside that particular project scope not outside. ok print `echo Yii::app()->user->id` on both place inside & outside the your project scope after logging and give me the response, what is the output?